# How to parse a date string in PHP?

Tags: php, date, parsing

With a date string of `Apr 30, 2010`, how can I parse the string into `2010-04-30` using PHP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert to a timestamp and then [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get it in your own format.

Comment: There's also a `date_parse` function that converts a string into an array with keys `year`, `month`, `day`, etc.

Answer (score 66):

Either with the DateTime API (*requires PHP 5.3+*):

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d, Y', 'Apr 30, 2010');
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

or the same in procedural style (*requires PHP 5.3+*):

```
$dateTime = date_create_from_format('F d, Y', 'Apr 30, 2010');
echo date_format($dateTime, 'Y-m-d');
```

or classic (*requires PHP4+*):

```
$dateTime = strtotime('Apr 30, 2010');
echo date('Y-m-d', $dateTime);
```