# php date string to timestamp - inverse_date()

Tags: php, parsing, date, inverse

I'm looking for a function that does the inverse of date(). Meaning:

```
$timestamp = inverse_date($format_string, $date_string);
$d = date($format_string, $timestamp);
if ($d === $date_string) {
    echo 'This is what I want';
}
```

Problems I've run into so far:

strtotime - guesses format, so it might not be good for all formats

strptime - uses strftime's formatting that is different from date's

**SOLUTION:**

```
function inverse_date($format_string, $date_string) {
    $dateTime = date_create_from_format($format_string, $date_string);
    $value_ts = date_format($dateTime, 'U');
    return $value_ts;
}
```

Thanks to Till Helge Helwig for the link.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2767419/989169) contains something helpful for you?

Comment: what's your desired input and output? I don't understand your question

Comment: why should strtotime not be ok? you can convert any english format date to a timestamp and the timestamp is easy to format then. You could prove the date first.

Comment: my desired input is a date string, and the format string (that I know), and the output is the timestamp. I need this to compare a given date string with the current timestamp to decide if it's in the past

Comment: strtotime guesses the format, and so I can't depend on it. What would you think when I give you 01/02/03 or 03-04-05?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function inverse_date($format_string, $date_string) {
    $dateTime = date_create_from_format($format_string, $date_string);
    $value_ts = date_format($dateTime, 'U');
    return $value_ts;
}
```