# Formatting date gives 12/31/1969

Tags: php

I'm trying to format a date in the form `mm-dd-yyyy` to the form `yyyy-mm-dd`, however, when I try formatting it, it comes out as `1969-12-31`.

Here's my code:

```
$custom_date = "10-13-2013";

$formatted_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($custom_date));
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You haven't posted the date you're starting with. Note that `strtotime()` is not infallible, and depending on exactly what you have in your date it can make some wild errors.

Comment: What is `$_GET['date']`

Comment: I'd suggest using `DateTime` with the `createFromFormat` method, which can parse the date based on the format you give.

Comment: There, edited the post.

Comment: as Mike said, and maybe using `htmlspecialchars` etc etc might mess up what's going into `strtotime`. At the end of the day, if someone puts a tag or something into your GET variable, date will still return a date of some sort so I'd suggest removing them.

Comment: here you go: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2891949/1974106). You have mm-dd-yyyy not dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: The european **standard** is day/month/year, that works
`echo  date("Y-m-d",strtotime("13-10-2013")), PHP_EOL;` ... for arbitrary format, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2767419/287948

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mm-dd-yyyy` is not a format that is recognised by `strtotime`. That's because it wouldn't reliably be able to handle dates like `03-04-2013`, it is the fourth of March or the third of April?

You need to parse it manually, or use the `DateTime` class.

```
list($m,$d,$y) = explode("-",$_GET['date']);
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y);
$formatted_date = date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks, decided to use DateTime::createFromFormat.

Answer (score 5):

```
$custom_date = "10-13-2013";

$formatted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $custom_date)->format("Y-m-d");
```