# JSON to PHP array dates to months results

Tags: php, arrays, json, date

Im busy with an chart of my Google Analytics.

I have made a JSON file with the dates and the visitors but now i got of each day of the year and I want to get the visitors each months.

Here is an example of the JSON results:

```
Dagindex,Gebruikers
1-1-2017,96
2-1-2017,116
3-1-2017,114
4-1-2017,101
5-1-2017,114
6-1-2017,111
7-1-2017,112
8-1-2017,96
9-1-2017,130
10-1-2017,123
11-1-2017,126
12-1-2017,116
13-1-2017,99
14-1-2017,88
15-1-2017,98
16-1-2017,150
17-1-2017,130
```

PHP Print_r() result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Dagindex] => 1-1-2017
            [Gebruikers] => 96
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Dagindex] => 2-1-2017
            [Gebruikers] => 116
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Dagindex] => 3-1-2017
            [Gebruikers] => 114
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Dagindex] => 4-1-2017
            [Gebruikers] => 101
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Dagindex] => 5-1-2017
            [Gebruikers] => 114
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Dagindex] => 6-1-2017
            [Gebruikers] => 111
        )
```

And what i want as result is like this:

```
01-2017 = XXXXX
02-2017 = XXXXX
03-2017 = XXXXX
till 12-2017 = XXXXX
```

Now i found this code below on stackoverflow, but i don't know how to change it for my results. Hope someone can help me out.

```
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$val){
   $result[substr($key,0,7)] += $val;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a date string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767324/how-to-parse-a-date-string-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that still isn't JSON. CSV, maybe? Anyway, it's largely irrelevant, since we already have the data in array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if this answer your question, but according to your json and the result you want, I should do more something like that:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    list($d,$m,$y) = explode("-", $value['Dagindex']);
    $result[$m.'-'.$y] += $value['Gebruikers'];
}
```

Comment: Also try this, its a short code but i get an "Notice: Undefined index: 1-2017 in"

Comment: hum, I forgot to add a security if the index is not existing... add a `if (!isset($result[$m.'-'.$y])) { $result[$m.'-'.$y] = 0; }` before the `$result[...] = ...`.

Comment: How can i add this :)

Comment: You just have to add it between the lines with `list()` and `$result`